# Please help me setup my hardware for our 3D Studio - Using Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, cuda

We have a small 3D animation studio and one of our more complicated scenes won't render because of the dreaded out of memory error.

We have the following 3D rigs:
PC 1 and 2 (same specs)
Blender - Latest
OS - Windows 11 64-bit
CPU - AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor - 3.70 GHz
GPU - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 8Gb Vram (Up to date NVIDIA Studio Drivers)
RAM Total - 32 GB

PC 3
Blender - Latest
OS - Windows 11 64-bit
CPU - AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor - 3.70 GHz
GPU - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 12Gb VRam (Up to date NVIDIA Studio Drivers)
RAM Total - 32 GB

We are trying to render the scene on PC 1 and 2 but they get the error. We are going to try run it on PC 3 and see if it even renders.
We want to do some upgrades but we have a limited budget (South African currency spending power is terrible)

Option 1: (R6000.00 x 2)
Buy 2x RTX 3050 8gb GPUs and run both PC 1 and 2 in SLI (2 cards per PC) will this help solve the Vram issue and will it decrease render time? (If not what will happen with the 2 cards and how to best configure them?)

Option 2: (R6500.00 x 2)
Buy 2x RTX 3060 12Gb GPUs and upgrade our 3050s - the least expensive option but probably the least amount of mileage and future-proofing. (Will the extra 4Gb of VRam be enough?)

Option 3: (R14 500.00 x 2)
Buy 2x RTX 4070 Super 12Gb Gpus and upgrade our 3050s - second most expensive possibly more future-proofing? (What performance difference will we feel from the 3050s to the 4070S? will it only be fast render time but will we still have the same Vram issue?)